# Algorithm to find distance of an uneven polygonal road

Tags: spatial-database, algorithm

While working for my summer internship I have got a task to implement an algorithm to find the crosssecting points of two roads or more and then place that cross-section point a number and then find the distance of the previous roads to the new point and update it in the table.

I tried **Ramer Douglas Peucker Line Simplification Algorithm** to convert the road into a straight line and then find the intersection point but the point coming after this is not exactly the cross section point and the distance coming is also not the exact.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

ArcGIS has the tool "Collapse Dual Lines To Centerline". A free solution, Jump Pilot, has the JUMP Skeletonizer Plugin that can be downloaded at SourceForge.